# How can I add a gap between each Instantiated object ? The prefabs should be Instantiated on the drawn circle and move inside: if (moveInCircles)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This will instantiate the prefab 10 times at the same position. And I want to add equal gap between the objects.

The prefabs should be instantiate on the drawn circle.
I want inside this:

```
if (moveInCircles)
```

To move in circles all the new prefabs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Spin")]
    public bool spin = true;
    public Vector3 Direction;
    [Range(0, 300)]
    public float speed = 10f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    public bool randomDirection = false;
    [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float timeDirChange;
    public Vector3 defaultDirection = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

    [Space(5)]

    [Header("Move in circles")]
    public bool moveInCircles = false;
    public GameObject rotateAroundTarget;
    public Vector3 axis;//by which axis it will rotate. x,y or z.
    public float rotationSpeed; //or the speed of rotation.
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;// upperLimit & lowerLimit: heighest & lowest height;
    [Range(5, 50)]
    public float radius = 5;
    private float height, prevHeight, time;//height:height it is trying to reach(randomly generated); prevHeight:stores last value of height;delay in radomness; 


    private float nextRotationTime = 0f;
    private int counter = 0;

    public DrawCircle dc;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int numOfObjects;
    public int gap = 3;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        dc.xradius = radius;

        if (prefab != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfObjects; i++)
            {


                Instantiate(prefab);

                var v = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Time.time * speed, Vector3.up) * new Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
                //prefab.transform.position = rotateAroundTarget.transform.position + v;
                prefab.transform.position = rotateAroundTarget.transform.position + v + new Vector3(rotateAroundTarget.transform.position.x * gap,0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomSpeed)
        {
            speed = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 300);
        }

        if (spin)
        {
            if (randomDirection == false)
            {
                nextRotationTime = 0;
                timeDirChange = 0;
                Direction = defaultDirection;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Time.time > nextRotationTime)
                {
                    nextRotationTime += timeDirChange;
                    RandomDirection();
                }
            }

            transform.Rotate(Direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            timeDirChange = 0;
            randomDirection = false;
            randomSpeed = false;
        }

        if (moveInCircles)
        {
            var v = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Time.time * speed, Vector3.up) * new Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
            transform.position = rotateAroundTarget.transform.position + v;
        }

        dc.xradius = radius;
    }

    private void RandomDirection()
    {
        Direction = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));
        while (Direction == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
        {
            counter++;
            Direction = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));

            if (counter == 2)
            {
                Direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `prefab.transform.position = rotateAroundTarget.transform.position + v + new Vector3(i, 0, 0);`